# Informix database from unix to Linux

Tags: unix, informix

We are going to migrate .net applications with Informix database as datasource systems from Unix to Linux server.

The informix databases are available in the existing Unix server.

As part of impact analysis we need to identify which are all other application types that might get impacted due to this migration of informix database system from unix to linux server.

In simple terms is there a way to identify what are all the applications that are using this existing informix database on unix system.

Thanks

Comment: Umm. not quite sure to understand the question. Are you looking for a way to know which applications are connecting to an Informix server ('onstat -g ses %session_id%' should show you the name of the 'program' connecting to the server) or are you asking for a way to know what interface (e.g. .net provider / odbc driver) the applications are using to connect?

Comment: yes i just wanted to know which are all applications or any other external database that are connecting to informix database. Is there a way to get the complete list.

Answer (score 1):

You can check all Informix sessions (connections) by examining `sysmaster:syssessions` table:

```
select * from sysmaster:syssessions
```

There are `username` and `hostname` columns which will help you to identify applications using Informix database.